# How do I plot this as a scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is killing me.
How do I modify this code so that the chart displays as a scatterplot instead of a line graph? I think it has something to do with this line but I dont know what ax=ax does.

```
data.plot(ax=ax)
```

Here is my code:

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.dates import MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU

#read data from csv selecting columns inline
data = pd.read_csv('EURCHF_Daily.csv', skipinitialspace=True,parse_dates=['Date'])
#set date as index
data.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
data = data.loc['2019/11/5':'2019/12/30']
#data = data[['Open','High','Low','Last']]
#data['High_Low_Mean'] = data['High'] - data['Low']
data = data[['Last']]

#plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
data.plot(ax=ax)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='White',rotation=90)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='White')
plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')

#set ticks every week
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=(MO, TU, WE, TH, FR,)))
#set major ticks format
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b %d'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plot()` function of a pandas DataFrame (which your `data` object is) uses a line plot by default.

You can use `DataFrame.plot.scatter(x, y)` to create a scatter plot of your data. The arguments x and y specify the columns of the DataFrame that will be used as the plot's X- and Y-axis.

See the documentation for more details:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I pre-format the 'Date' column from the dataframe so that when it is added to the graph, I get a shortened date version?

Comment: Did you leave in the 'ax=ax' parameter in your call of data.plot.scatter()? It tells matplotlib which axis to use for the plot - only this way the formatter will apply and the dates will be formatted correctly.

I recommend you reading the documentations of matplotlib and pandas to get a better understanding of how they work.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add `plt.scatter(x, y)` to your code where `x` and `y` are the columns of Dataframe. 
It will generate the proper graph as per your requirement.
Also put the code `plt.show()` to show the graph.

See for more details: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

Comment: Thank you for answering. The only problem with this is that I don't know how to modify the 'date' column with 'set_major_formatter'

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `scatter` from the standard matplotlib, setting the date (the index of the dataframe) as `x` and the closing value as `y`. As the default `xlim` is much too wide in this case, the code sets it using the first and last date.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import MO, TU, WE, TH, FR

dates = ['2019-12-02', '2019-12-03', '2019-12-04', '2019-12-05', '2019-12-06', '2019-12-09', '2019-12-10',
         '2019-12-11', '2019-12-12', '2019-12-13', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-17', '2019-12-18', '2019-12-19',
         '2019-12-20', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-24', '2019-12-25', '2019-12-26', '2019-12-27', '2019-12-30',
         '2019-12-31']
close = [1.0981, 1.0936, 1.0957, 1.0954, 1.0943, 1.0930, 1.0913, 1.0936, 1.0958, 1.0937, 1.0950, 1.0929, 1.0898,
         1.0877, 1.0880, 1.0889, 1.0866, 1.0880, 1.0889, 1.0881, 1.0849, 1.0853]

data = pd.DataFrame({'Close': close}, index=pd.to_datetime(dates))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
plt.scatter(data.index, data.Close, color='crimson')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='black', rotation=90)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='black')
ax.set_xlim(data.index[0] - pd.offsets.Hour(12), data.index[-1]+ pd.offsets.Hour(12))
#set ticks every week
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=(MO, TU, WE, TH, FR)))
# set major ticks format
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b %d'))
# automatically set the padding to fit everything
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]